# How can I change code colors in Jupyter-lab installed with pip?

Tags: pip, jupyter-lab, color-scheme

How can I change the colors of code instructions in Jupyterlab installed with pip? For Anaconda I do it through the index.css file but for Jupyterlab installed with pip I don't know how to customize the code colors. For example, changing the green color of "import" to purple:

[green color code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB51u.png)

[purple color code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLbCj.png)

I could not realize how to customize the code colors.

Comment: It's my understanding they come from CodeMirror. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-inline-syntax-highlighting/12779/4?u=fomightez) and [here](https://codemirror.net/examples/styling/) and [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10095).

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-can-i-change-code-colors-in-jupyter-lab-installed-via-pip/20147?u=fomightez). Please don't cross-post without linking in all places you post the same content. This saves people helping you from repeating something. Also it helps others following in your footsteps with the same issue, find the solution. They won't know to look at the related place if not linked. Remember the person you may be helping find the solution could be yourself months from now when you stumble upon the same issue.